# Wpf DataGridComboBox Column Not Displaying ComboBox List

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid combobox column to display a list.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding OilType,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Type" ItemsSource="{Binding OilTypes,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="OilType" />
```

The bound object is

```
class Foo
{
public Foo()
{
OilTypes--->Collection is loaded here
}
public string OilType{get;set;}

public ObservableCollection<OilType> OilTypes{get;set;}
.
.

}

class OilType
{
string Type{get;set;}
.
.
.

}
```

I don't understand why the comboBox list is not displayed.